# Wave problem in 1-D with boundary condition not an odd function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem $1D$ wave problem in my notes

\begin{align} 
u_{tt} &= c^2u_{xx} \\
u(0,t) &= u(L, t) = 0 \\
u(x,0) &= f(x) \\
u_t(x,0)&= g(x)
\end{align}

with solution

$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[B_n \cos \left(\frac{c n \pi t}{L} \right) + B_{n}^{*} \sin \left(\frac{c n \pi t}{L} \right) \right] \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)$$

where

$$B_n = \frac {2}{L} \int_{0}^L f(x) \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx$$

I am wondering why is it not $$B_n = \frac {1}{L} \int_{-L}^L f(x) \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx$$ since I do not know if $f(x)$ is odd or even or neither ? This seems to assume that the integrand is even.

Another way of asking this question is that if a function has a representation

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)$$

does this mean the function is odd?

Edit: I guess I am just confused how the correct $B_n$ is obtained. As pointed out by John B, $f$ is only defined on $[0,L]$.

Comment: The answer to your last question is obviously yes (why?). But $f$ is not defined on $[-L,0)$, so how could $B_n$ be the second integral?

Comment: @JohnB right. I think the answer is because it is a sum of odd functions, but it is an infinite sum so I'm not sure that still applies. Can you expand why the first integral is correct. I am not sure.

Comment: Just make the usual computations (you say that you have some notes, the computations should be there). As for the function at the end, write $f(-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin(-n\pi x/L)=\cdots$.

Comment: @JohnB ok I understand now, thanks for your time.